# "Pay With A Tweet" button on top of tumblr posts?

Tags: css, iframe

I'm trying to add my iframe "paywithatweet" button on top of my tumblr theme.
I want the button to be at the same position all the time, and not affected by scrolling through posts.

```
<div style="position:absolute; left:77; top:77; width:377; height:377; clip:rect(0,381,381,0); background:#FFF;">
  <iframe src="paywithatweet.com/…; class="spaced-right" name="paytweet_button" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" height="48px" width="292px"></iframe>
</div>
```

Apologies if that's a stupid question as it sounds easy...

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: What have you tried? Where do you get stuck? Or are you just asking us to do the work for you?

Comment: I was trying to wrap the iframe into a div container and then place in in my body tag, but this could be terribly wrong...                                                    <div style="position:absolute; left:77; top:77; width:377; height:377; clip:rect(0,381,381,0); background:#FFF;">

 <iframe src="http://www.paywithatweet.com/dlbutton03.php?id=44c5ccf8-4fce-4303-95fc-09096698d4a5" class="spaced-right" name="paytweet_button" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" height="48px" width="292px"></iframe>

</div>

Comment: @AlbertPukies `position: absolute` won't keep the element at the top all the time. Try `position: fixed` and add some `px` to your values. A demo of the issue would really help.